# How can I write Node.js web services in a DRY manner?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dry

I'm writing a bunch of web services which all share some common patterns.  For example they all share the same requires

```
var x = require(...);
var y = require(...);
```

do similar authentication

```
var auth = express.basicAuth(...);
server.use(auth);
```

and have similar error messages.

```
server.error(function(err, req, res, next){
    ...
});
```

Is there some way of writing the above in one common place so that if anything changes I can make a single change rather than five or six?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. You can create a module which will return a base http server which implements the settings / methods that are common to all of your services. From there you can just require that module, and add additional service methods do it.

The module would look something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

//  Configure

//  Common Functionality
app.error(function(err, req, res, next){
    ...
});

exports.app = app;
```

And then you can use this module like so:

```
var service = require('./service-base').app;

service.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    //  get and return users
});

service.listen(1234);
```

If you need to expose other items from the module you can easily do that to make them available in the service implementation files as well.

Comment: Thanks Timothy.  The last piece of the puzzle is require.  Is there any way to centralize var blah = require(...) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the example pseudo code I have, most of the requires will likely be in the service-base. Then you just have to require the service base, and it should expose whatever you want to be able to customize. How would you further centralize that?